# iOS8.1 Can't stay logged in to Stack Exchange or Stack Exchange chat

Tags: ipad, safari, bug

So everything was wonderful before iOS8.1. Now I can no longer log in to Stack Exchange via Facebook on Safari (diagnostics say it's an HTML 5 issue), but *can* log in via Facebook on Chrome or via Stack Exchange on Safari. However, if I leave the screen, either going to another Safari tab or another app, I have to log in all over again. This never used to happen in "the good old days."

I gather Apple is still not fixing all the things that are broken in Safari (for example, certain videos won't even load or play). I went to the extent of completely reinstalling the iOS via iTunes.

I'm running one of the early iPad minis (fall 2012).

Any ideas?

Comment: Try: iOS 8.1.3.

Comment: Sigh. No better.

Comment: do you have keychain enabled to remember your passwords etc

Comment: @soulshined: Yes, it works everywhere else :P

Comment: iOS 8.2 is now available for the iPad